# Sphinx Config: Adding manual column what is not found on MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I have 2 databases in Mysql, i use the same Sphinx config to index them.
I want to be able to add a manual column via Sphinx config example "table_id" this way i can know from what table the id is found via Sphinx.

This is my config with table_id ( example ) but is not working and column is not found on Mysql
This way i don't need to create new columns via Mysql Table.

```
source v_v1_src_p1
{
  type                    = mysql

  sql_host                = 127.0.0.1
  sql_user                = root
  sql_pass                = 
  sql_db                  = 
  sql_port                = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

  sql_query_pre           = SET NAMES utf8

  sql_query = SELECT \
    id as id, \
    unique_id, \
    v_id, \
    v_title, \
    status, \
    table_id = 1 \
    FROM cache_v_t1 ;

  sql_field_string = unique_id
  sql_field_string = v_id
  sql_field_string = v_title
  sql_attr_uint = status
  sql_attr_uint = table_id
}

# Part 2

source v_v1_src_p2
{
  type                    = mysql

  sql_host                = 127.0.0.1
  sql_user                = root
  sql_pass                = 
  sql_db                  = 
  sql_port                = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

  sql_query_pre           = SET NAMES utf8

  sql_query = SELECT \
    id as id, \
    unique_id, \
    v_id, \
    v_title, \
    status, \
    table_id = 2 \
    FROM cache_v_t2 ;

  sql_field_string = unique_id
  sql_field_string = v_id
  sql_field_string = v_title
  sql_attr_uint = status
  sql_attr_uint = table_id
}
```

Any suggestion can i can make this?

Answer (score 0):

The way you written it, its an equality check, against a column (which as say doesnt exist).

Should be written using `AS`:

```
...
status, \
1 AS `table_id` \
FROM cache_v_t1 
...
status, \
2 AS `table_id` \
FROM cache_v_t2 
...
```

The backtick quotes are optional, but recommended.